# What exactly do the PropertyChanged.Notify extension method?

Tags: c#, .net

In this code I noticed the .Notify method is an extension method. Why and what is the code behind this method?

```
public class Notifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    (...)

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(Expression<Func<object>> property)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged.Notify(property);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking why the method takes an Expression instead of a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This extension method isn't provided by the .NET framework.** Therefore, it is a custom extension method created somewhere in your code. To know what exactly it does, navigate to it and look at the source code (F12).

Generally speaking, I assume it will raise the `PropertyChanged` event with the property name extracted from the expression that is passed to it.

Comment: .Notify is not a Microsoft extention method. My mistake... I ll close the question

Answer (score 0):

INotifyPropertyChanged interface is used to specify to subscribed clients that value of the property has been changed. To implement it, you have to declare a PropertyChanged event.

.Notify as you have mentioned is an extension method. The soul purpose of this .Notify must be to raise this event. 
Internally it must be raising the event by doing something like this

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
```

For more information look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx)